# handling config yaml files in setup.py

Tags: python, package, yaml, config, setup.py

I have a pycharm project with the following shape:

```
my_project:
    setup.py
    config_files:
        config1.yaml
        config2.yaml
    my_package:
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

When I run my `main.py` from pycharm, I am able to access my `config1.yaml` file using the following path: `../config_files/config1.yaml`.

My goal is to build the package, then install it on my cloud machine and run the program. But the `setup.py` does not copy the config files where they are in my pycharm project.

My question is: what can I do to be sure that these files are correctly copied?

Comment: What do you mean by `not copied correctly`? Do you want to transfer the whole directory to your cloud and execute it locally on that cloud-machine or do you want to get something like a remote installation?

Comment: I want to build a package and then install it via pip and git on my cloud isntance